# how to make app run as under root on non rooted device

Tags: applications, root-access, system-apps

I'm making some apps for internal use in one company and I need to make my apps run as system apps (as on rooted device) but with out rooting it. I'm thinking of root device, put packages to /data/priv-app directory and unroot it, but I'm not sure that it will work and my app would work as system apps. So my question - how to make app run as system app with possibility to delete file in /system and so on (without making custom firmware).

Comment: How to ride a bicycle without a bicycle? Not at all. Sorry, not possible.

Comment: Not entirely impossible - devices with unlockable bootloader would allow flashing a recovery without root, then one could implant the app into `/system` without actually rooting the device. However, newer Android devices employ write protection on `/system`, which one could only circumvent by flashing a kernel that disables it. With this kind trouble, you might as well just root the phone via that recovery you flashed instead.